# Calculations on the iteration count in for loop

Tags: ruby, indexing, iteration

I was playing around with Ruby and Latex to create a color coding set for a registor. I have the following block of code. When attempting to run this, `band1` = `1e+02.`

I tried `band1` = `(BigDecimal(i) * 100).to_f`, thinking maybe there was some odd floating point issue.  An integer multiplied by an integer should create an integer.  I tried a variety of other things as well, but to no avail.

```
(1..9).each do |i|       #Band 1
  (0..9).each do |j|     #Band 2
    (0..11).each do |k|  #Band 3
      #Band 3 Start
      #these are the colors of the resistor bands
      b1 = $c_band12[i]
      b2 = $c_band12[j]
      b3 = $c_band3[k]
      b4 = "Gold"

      oms = ((i*100) + (j*10)) * $mult[k]
      band1 = i*100
      band2 = j
      band3 = $mult[k]
    end
  end
end
```

Not sure what I'm missing.  Should I be using `each_with_index` through these iterations?  I  tried this:

```
(1..9).each_with_index {|i, indexi|       #Band 1
  (0..9).each_with_index {|j, indexj|     #Band 2
    (0..11).each_with_index {|k, indexk|  #Band 3
      #Band 3 Start
      #these are the colors of the resistor bands
      b1 = $c_band12[i]
      b2 = $c_band12[j]
      b3 = $c_band3[k]
      b4 = "Gold"

      oms = ((i*100) + (j*10)) * $mult[k]
      band1 = indexk * 100
```

and I got the same answer. I can't see why `1*100` should equate to such a large number.

edit: Additional info:  If I have this: `band1=i*10` 
then the calculation is correct. In fact, the calculation is correct up to 99.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `band1` has to be a `Fixnum`. Check with `p band1.class`. Not sure how you get "1e+02", maybe you print in some strange fashion, or you do `band1 == 1e+02` which returns `true` in Ruby. You must use `eql?` to distinguish between `1` and `1.0`:

```
1 ==   1.0  # => true
1.eql?(1.0) # => false
```

Comment: Yes, mult does have float values.  But,the value for i is an integer (no decimals), and multiplying 100 with it does not give me what I expect. 

I would expect 1*100 to equal 100, I'm receiving 1*100 = 1e+02 (first iteration)

Comment: Oups, misread your question. Next time keep it to a strict minimum; it will also help you understand better.

Comment: Not a problem --

Yes, I was seeing that band1 should be Fixnum (can't quite remember why, I believe variable assignment, doesn't matter).

Not sure how I'm getting that value either.  Possibly LaTeX is transcribing it that way.

Comment: And, since I'm having issues editing my answer:  Thank you for the information.  I'll take a look at the band1.class